# How to have my car near me when missions start?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I've just started playing GTA Online a few days ago and would like to know something about player vehicles.

For example when you join or start a mission, I can see other players' vehicles parked near the mission start location.

I have purchased a car, and I would like to know how to have it spawn near me when missions start.

When you play in heists, you can select which car do you want to drive, but how can I do that when normal missions start?

Answer (score 3):

Your vehicle will only appear near you when the mission starts if the following conditions are met:

1. It is a personal vehicle (it shows a picture of a vehicle on the map).
2. You used it right before you started the mission (I always accept missions while sitting in my vehicle of choice to guarantee I'll be able to use it).

If you fail to satisfy both of the conditions, you can always call your mechanic to bring you your ride (assuming its not destroyed/impounded).

This works in all mission types that can be started/joined from your phone.

Comment: 1. afaik it showed this icon, yes.
2. mhm I'll try sitting inside tomorrow then.
thanks

Comment: Were you sitting in the vehicle when you started the mission?

Comment: @CopsOwner Please remember to come back tomorrow telling us if it worked or not :)

Comment: sure xd, and no, I didn't sit inside (if I remember correctly lol)

Comment: Nice answer!
@CopsOwner - Don't forget that you need a tracker on your vehicle! And sometimes it can spawn your car far away from where you are if you enter a mission outside your car (must be a bug).

Answer (score 1):

You can only use your personal cars in heists, "free roam" jobs given by npc's and racing jobs with custom cars enabled, if you own a personal car in the class required for the job.

If you are in a race job that allows custom cars and you own a car in that class, your car will show up in the vehicle selection screen and will have "Custom" prefixed to the car name.

In missions where you have to travel the map to get to your target, your car will be parked nearby if you were in the car when you joined the job.

Comment: Not really heist/races, just random task. So we're 4 ppl in a lobby. When host press start session, we're going to complete smthg. Exactly at this place other ppl's cars are parked right few feets away from them, but mine is not here. So how can I get/park my car to this starting place like other ppl/cars? :h

Comment: I forgot about the missions given by npc's that allow you to travel the map to your objective. Added that to my answer.

Comment: I think it works when I sit in my car before taking any mission. Thanks for the help guys :3